# Pyspark read existing parquet file with new schema return NULL content

Tags: parquet, pyspark-schema

Firstly, I read a csv file and save it to parquet format dataframe.
After that, when I read this parquet data file with my new custom schema, returned dataframe has new schema but all NULL content.
Comparing with old schema, I only change column names, all column type(string type) remains the same.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyxPp.png)

As far as I know, schema metada will be created along while we write to parquet file. Does that mean we're not able change schema after data saved into parquet? I was expecting I can change atleast column name when reading